# Parsing Tweets for #hashtags and @usernames using iOS for multiple languages

Tags: javascript, ios, regex, parsing, hashtag

I want to transform a tweet for display in a UIWebView. I want to convert the #hashtags and @usernames into html links which I then will handle.

I have found some solutions using regular expressions but most seem to have problems as email addresses and web links can have the '@' character in them.

Does anyone know of an appropriate way to do this in Objective-C? Can it be done using regular expressions, which are available in [iOS 4 and later](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? Or do I need to get funky with a parser?

Oh yeah, forgot to mention, I want this to work for all languages. (arabic, chinese, german etc...)

Comment: Argh haha I needed an Objective-c solution, found this javascript solution, but I'm not using UIWebView /: Converting RegEx to ObjC shouldn't be too hard though :) Modified question tags so others don't find a false result like I did!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this in a webview, why don't you go ahead and use javascript? I've done this in a project, where links had to be found automatically. I couldn't depend on the data detector of the webview so a short javascript helped:

```
someTweet.replace(
   /(\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig,
   "<a href='$1'>$1</a>"
)
```

The regex is simple and might not catch every url out there but it did most of the time. Transferring this to usernames and hashtags shouldn't be too difficult.

**usernames** consist of characters, numbers and _ so @([1-9a-zA-Z_]+) will match them.

```
someTweet.replace(
   /@([1-9a-zA-Z_]+)/,
   "<a href='http://twitter.com/$1'>@$1</a>")
)
```

**hashtags**, I am not sure about these: I assume they are anything starting with a # and terminates with a whitespace, # or @, but that's just guessing. #([^\s#@]*) might work.

```
someTweet.replace(
   /#([^\s#@]*)/,
   "<a href='http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1'>#$1</a>"
)
```